# PHP set a lot of variables based on increasing numbers

Tags: php, loops, variables, for-loop

I need the variables u1, u2, u3, u4 ... u559 and u560 to be set to # in PHP.

I have tried:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 560; $x++) {
$u{$x} = "#"; }
```

But it didn't seem to work. Any help?

Comment: `${"u$x"} = "#";`

Comment: Just use $u$x it should do the trick!

Comment: Why do you need all those different variables? Usually an array is used for things like this.

Comment: Also what @Don'tPanic says :-)

Comment: Works now, thanks! To those who want to know **why**, I am experiementing... :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. Just curious. But just FYI, if you end up experimenting with an array instead, `$u = array_fill(1, 560, '#');`, which can be accessed with `$u[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're best off making a single string, then assigning that string as a variable name.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 560; $x++) {
    $var = 'u' . $x;
    $$var = "#";
}
```

However, wouldn't an array fit your purposes?

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 560; $x++) {
    $u[$x] = "#";
}
```